# Tastypie django, missing column

Tags: django, tastypie

So i am trying to interact with my tastypie django api. I have created the following models in django:

```
#/models.py
from django.db import models
from tastypie.utils.timezone import now
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Project(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

class ProjectImage(models.Model):
  Project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
  Photo = models.FileField(upload_to = 'images') 
  PhotoName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

And the following resources:

```
#/api.py
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from photod.models import Project
from tastypie.authorization import DjangoAuthorization,Authorization
from tastypie.authentication import BasicAuthentication
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from tastypie import fields
from tastypie.serializers import Serializer

# We need a User resource as it is a required field on the project model.
class UserResource(ModelResource):
 class Meta:
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'user'
    excludes = ['email', 'password', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser'] 
    authorization = Authorization()
    serializer = Serializer(formats=['json', 'jsonp'])

class ProjectResource(ModelResource):
user = fields.ToOneField( UserResource, 'created_by_user', full = True )
class Meta:
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'project' 
    authorization = Authorization()
    serializer = Serializer(formats=['json', 'jsonp'])
```

Now i want to populate the project resource with the following command:

```
 curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"name": "The first proj", "pub_date": "2011-05-22T00:46:38", "user": "/api/v1/user/1/"}' http://localhost:1337/api/v1/project/
```

But i get an error message as such:

```
HTTP/1.0 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
Date: Wed, 28 May 2014 05:47:29 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.3
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: application/json

{"error_message": "table photod_project has no column named user_id", "traceback":
"Traceback (most recent call last):\n\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 195, in wrapper\n    
response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)\n\n  
File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 426, in dispatch_list\n    return self.dispatch('list', request, **kwargs)\n\n  
File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 458, in dispatch\n    response = method(request, **kwargs)\n\n  
File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1320, in post_list\n    updated_bundle = self.obj_create(bundle, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))\n\n  
File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 2084, in obj_create\n    return self.save(bundle)\n\n  
File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 2230, in save\n    bundle.obj.save()\n\n  
File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py\", line 545, in save\n    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)\n\n  
File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py\", line 573, in save_base\n    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)\n\n  
File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py\", line 654, in _save_table\n    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)\n\n  
File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py\", line 687, in _do_insert\n    using=using, raw=raw)\n\n  
File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py\", line 232, in _insert\n    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)\n\n  
File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py\", line 1514, in insert_query\n    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)\n\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py\", line 903, in execute_sql\n    cursor.execute(sql, params)\n\n  
File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py\", line 69, in execute\n    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)\n\n  
File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py\", line 53, in execute\n    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)\n\n  
File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py\", line 99, in __exit__\n    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)\n\n  
File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py\", line 53, in execute\n    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)\n\n 
File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py\", line 451, in execute\n    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)\n\nOperationalError: 
table photod_project has no column named user_id\n"}
```

What is wrong? Why do i need a colum named user_id? how do i implement it? am I just way of the mark here? all help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely ran `syncdb` before adding the `user` `ForeignKey` to your `Project` model, so the `user_id` column (which represents the `ForeignKey`) does not exist.

If you're still developing and don't care about the data in your database, just remove the database file and run `syncdb` again. If you do care about the data, look into [`south`](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for a data migration.

The issue has nothing to do with the API, if you opened the Django admin you'd get the same error.

Comment: Thank you! Sadly I just got a new error message, maby you can help me out with that as well? : "error_message": "photod_project.user_id may not be NULL",

Comment: @BAYELK Didn't you call your user field `created_by_user`? Try submitting that and not `user`.

Comment: Parhaps i could be so bold  as to ask one more question, now that it works  with curl i tried doing a simular request from my front-end (angular)return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://85.228.204.92:1337/api/v1/project/',
        //http://85.228.234.52:1337/api/v1/project/ 
     }); and i get this in the console: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://85.222.234.52:1337/api/v1/project/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://85.222.234.52' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @BAYELK Read the answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-w — make sure you understand the implications of allow cross-origin access.